# Are eternity splinter drop rates different in different locations?

Tags: marvel-heroes

I know that there is a timer for eternity splinter drops but I was wondering if drop rates vary for different locations. While splinters will drop every 8 minutes or so, the amount that drop can be changed by equipping items with a "special item find" increase. That makes me believe that there is a varying drop rate for eternity splinters, based on special item find percentage. Is there also a difference in drop rates (or rather, the number of splinters in a drop) based on location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time of still wondering this, I found a fairly new forum post regarding Eternity Splinters

You can see it [HERE](https://forums.marvelheroesomega.com/discussion/236/eternity-splinter-research).

It's basically a small research paper on ES drops in the game. But, in overview, Eternity Splinter drops happen somewhere around *a drop per 6-8 minutes* and the only thing that can change the number of splinters dropped is your *Special Item Find* stat and pure luck. It's not based on location and the RNG mostly seems like a case of *"You get 1 or you get more than 1"* and there's no concrete number of whether you're going to get 1,2,3,4 or 5 splinters in a drop.